# Bootstrap - how to avoid linebreak on large screens

Tags: bootstrap-4

My question is:

### How am I able to get rid of the linebreak in number 3)?

I have the following example:

```
<div class="container align-items-center justify-content-center mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-xs-6 offset-xs-3">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Change Password</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can watch it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/exqrgm5v/1/

1) If the window is small, there should be a linebreak:

[image]

2) If the window gets bigger, there should be no linebreak:

[image]

### 3) But if the window gets bigger, the linebreak comes again:

[image]

4) And if it gets even bigger, there is no linebreak again:

[image]

Comment: When the window gets bigger, the linebreak occurs?

Comment: yes, check the fiddle!

Comment: I asked because it doesn't happen on my side.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Bootstrap, you have a class `text-nowrap` that you can play with depending of the different screen sizes. **Depending of what are your needs, you may apply one of them below:**

```html
<p class="text-nowrap">Some text</p>
<p class="text-sm-nowrap">Some text</p>
<p class="text-md-nowrap">Some text</p>
<p class="text-lg-nowrap">Some text</p>


<p class="text-wrap">Some text</p>
<p class="text-sm-wrap">Some text</p>
<p class="text-md-wrap">Some text</p>
<p class="text-lg-wrap">Some text</p>
```

And because you said there *should* be a linebreak when the window is small, you would want to use `text-lg-nowrap` with your example.

Comment: Doesn't work in Bootstrap 4+ version: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow

Answer (score 1):

You can use `text-nowrap` on the page header.

```
<div class="container align-items-center justify-content-center mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-6 mx-auto">
      <div class="page-header text-nowrap">
        <h1>Change Password</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also simplify the column structure. FYI, there is no -xs in Bootstrap 4. This was making `col-xs-6` not do anything and therefore become full width on the smallest screen.

https://codeply.com/p/Bd5R4HPFDh

Answer (score 1):

**You can't.**

There is no possible way in `Bootstrap 4` to do or do not a `nowrap` depending on the size of the screen. Not even in `Bootstrap 5`.

So for example if you want to have an element with `nowrap` activated only when the screen is 992px or bigger (Desktop) you should write something like this in your `CSS`:

```
.dontWrapIt{
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .dontWrapIt{
    white-space: normal !important;
  }
}
```

And write this in your `HTML`:

```
<div class="container align-items-center justify-content-center mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-4 col-md-6 offset-md-3 col-sm-8 offset-sm-2 col-xs-6 offset-xs-3">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h1 class="dontWrapIt">Change Password</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```